# Date format in Power BI desktop doesn't match Power BI app

Tags: powerbi

I am facing a weird issue where the date format in my Power BI Desktop doesn't match the date format in Power BI app after the report is published. In Power BI desktop, I have it set to dd/mm/yyyy but after it has been published, it reverts back to mm/dd/yyyy. Please see the screenshot below. Screen on the left is from Power BI App and on the right is from Power BI Desktop.

[image: PowerBI]

What would be the reason for that? All I am doing is selecting the field that has been used for the slicer, going to "Column Tools", then changing Data Type to "Date" and Format to "dd/mm/yyyy". Is there any other way of setting that?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Maybe with Locale setting in Transform data?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post (sorry for bringing up history) but the answer to this lies in the Application you're using to view PowerBI Service. Example - If you're Australian using Google Chrome you need to make sure your language setting is set to English(Australian). This will update the display of powerBI Service in Chrome to dd/mm/yyyy. It's a commonly overlooked issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at changing your default data format setting on your Microsoft 365 instance? If not go into your Microsoft 365 Admin setting and change your regional format there.